# how to display different image one one line in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I am using a basic CSS class to display an unordered list.

The CSS class assigns an icon to each line, however I would like to change the icon for just one line, with out affecting any of the other lines or other list on my site. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: "Line" meaning, list item element, `li`? Well then go find a way to uniquely identify that element - like add a class or ID to it, if you can manipulate the HTML structure, or identify it based on its relation to other elements ...

Comment: Please ignore this question unless you can think of a better way, resolved with <li style="list-style-image: url('images/Cannot.png');">This is a new list icon</li>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you put in an `id` in the tag, it will only affect that one, like this:

```
    .image-list-item {
      content: url("");
    }

    #image {
      content: url("");
    }
```

```
    <div>
      <img class="image-list-item">
      <img class="image-list-item" id="image">
      <img class="image-list-item">
    </div>
```

Try this. If it doesn't work delete the class in the image that has the id, then try it again.

Comment: Rendered the icon, however the text re not displayed, at least give me something to work with, Many thanks

Comment: What do yo mean by text?